# Why webbroswer.open() can not recognize non-english word in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

I made a very very simple program like below :

```
import webbrowser

a = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + '강남'
webbrowser.open(a)
```

When I execute this program, the browser is open with url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/??'

Why does it accept Korean as '??" ?. Is it related with unicode-something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URIs (and therefore URLs) can only contain ASCII characters. You must [encode](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) non-ASCII characters, like this:

```
import webbrowser
import urllib.request

a = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + urllib.request.quote('강남', '')
webbrowser.open(a)
```

Modern browsers will then render the escaped URL (but not interpret it, for example when you copy it) :

[image: Chrome rendering of Unicode URL]